# When I am adding content type to Task List , not able to see all content type group

Tags: content-type, task-list

When I am trying to add content type to Task List. It is not showing all groups.[image: attached image for reference]
I am able to see folder content type group in sharpoint 2010.
[image]

Comment: It will only show supported content type by the `Task List`. I am getting the same count for adding content type.

Comment: Hi Pradip , I am able to see "Folder Content Type" group in 2010 but not in 2013.

Comment: Actually `Folder Content Type` doesn't appear at my end as well. It is appearing for Custom List. So I can say that content type is not supported by the task list.

Comment: I have edited the question and added screenshot from 2010.